# Restart Gradle without restarting Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Restarting Gradle when android studio shows that I have errors fixes them sometimes. Is it possible to restart Gradle without restarting android studio as it takes a while for it to load on my machine.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this question? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 5):

You can write the following onto the terminal tab in android studio:

```
gradlew --stop
```

After it executes successfuly it can take some few seconds to take effect (not more than a minute). The point is that it'll have to end the current task it'll be processing at that moment. If the task is frozen this command won't work.

As you already might know you can find all the tasks being processing at gradle console tab in android studio.

Comment: on mac `./gradlew --stop`